# Grub wont boot windows after install

Tags: windows, grub

I have a machine where I just installed Endeavour in its own disk. I’ve configured OS probe to allow the detection and addition of windows to grub but despite the system being found it cannot boot. Some relevant info:

```
sudo os-prober 
[sudo] senha para vfbsilva: 
/dev/nvme0n1p2:Manjaro Linux (23.1.0):ManjaroLinux:linux
/dev/sdd2@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
```

Then I update the entries:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Gerando o arquivo de configuração do grub...
Plano de fundo encontrado: /usr/share/endeavouros/splash.png
Imagem Linux encontrada: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Imagem initrd encontrada: /boot/amd-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot:  amd-ucode.img initramfs-linux-fallback.img
Aviso: os-prober será executado para detectar outras partições de arranque.
A sua saída será usada para detectar binários de arranque nessas partições e criar novas entradas.
Encontrado Manjaro Linux (23.1.0) em /dev/nvme0n1p2
Encontrado Windows Boot Manager em /dev/sdd2@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
A adicionar entrada de menu para UEFI Firmware Settings ...
concluído
```

There is some problem where Endeavour and Manjaro are bootable but windows not. I’m not using fastboot and manjaros grub can access the windows install. The error from endeavours grub is the following:
[image]

This is a quite obvious problem, so I installed grub customizer and in endeavour I have:

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd3,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd3,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd3,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci3,gpt2  3E6D-7A34
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3E6D-7A34
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

For the windows loader. The manjaro loader has:

savedefault
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd3,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd3,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd3,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci3,gpt2  3E6D-7A34
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3E6D-7A34
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

So they are equal hence I cannot grasp the problem.

I think it mighrt be related to:

ls /boot/efi/EFI/
boot/        endeavouros/
```

There is no Microsoft entry but why?

Comment: Grub Customizer replaces grub with its own proxy files. Sometimes that make grub issues worse. Are all installs in UEFI boot mode. Have you  updated UEFO and NVMe to latest firmware. Some systems need that for kernel & drivers to work. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Only use Boot-Repair's advanced mode.

Comment: thanks for the tips, it seems boot-repair is not avaliable arch derivatives how can I tackle it?

Comment: Boot-Repair is just running a variety of commands to document your system or grub update. Its advanced mode can do a full grub reinstall. So you can do all those things in Arch manually from a live installer. I do not use Arch, but often refer to its wiki support pages as they often are better or more up to date than others. Just some commands are different and need translating to Debian based systems.

Comment: This user has multiple boot stanza in 40_custom. examples from cavfan
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392441&p=13816046#post13816046 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Answer (score 1):

The GRUB configuration assumes that the UEFI bootloader/boot manager for Windows is located in a FAT filesystem with a volume serial number 3E6D-7A34.

But the error message suggests this might not be true.

You should run `lsblk -o +uuid` to see the list of filesystems with their UUIDs (or volume serial numbers in case of FAT filesystems, which don't have a real UUID). What is the UUID reported for `/dev/sdd2`? If it is not 3E6D-7A34, you should place the correct value to the `search` lines within the Windows block in `grub.cfg`.

Since EndeavourOS is on a different disk, it has its own EFI System Partition (ESP for short) which contains only its own bootloader.
Maybe `os-prober` expects all the OSs to share a single ESP and so the resulting config refers to the wrong disk/partition?